# Angular Filter Data by id

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some data in an angular project which I want to use instead of a database as it's very little data...about 50 id's with 5 fields...here is the data:

```
mydata = [

  {
    "id": 3,
    "active": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "text": "this is some text from 3"
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "active": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "text": "this is some text from 31"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "active": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "text": "this is some text for 11"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "active": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "text": "this is some text from 21"
  }

]
```

Then I have a method:

```
getDataText(id) {
    // code to get the text of the data with the selected id
    // do it should get me the data (in this case the text from id 11) 
}
```

Then in the component.html file I have:

```
<button (click)="getDataText(11)">Get Data by Id</button>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: keep an extra array which keeps the filtered data

Comment: you can use filter operator: this.mydata.filter(x=>x.id==11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
getDataText(id) {
    let findedData = this.myData.find(i => i.id === id);
    if (typeof findedData === 'undefined') {
       return null;
    }
    return findedData;
}
```

Note, if nothing found with condition, result will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

`getDataText(id) {
    const result = this.mydata.filter(x => x.id === id);
    return result;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your `getDataText` should looks like:

```
getDataText(id) {
  const data = myData.find(x => x.id === id);
  return data ? data.text : `Cannot find data with id ${id}`;
}
```

You could even split in two methods:

```
getDataById(id) {
  return myData.find(x => x.id === id);
}

getDataText(id) {
  const data = this.getDataById(id);
  return data ? data.text : `Cannot find data with id ${id}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getDataText = id => (this.myData.find(i => i.id === id) || {}).text;
```

This will return the text of the item with the given id, or undefined if there is no item with the given id.

Answer (score 0):

```
public result = "Get Data by Id";
public getDataText(id) {
  const reqObj = this.mydata.find(item => item.id === id);
  this.result = reqObj ? reqObj.text : 'nothing found';
}


<button (click)="getDataText(11)">{{result})</button>
```

Here you can see my [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/v34680l1r0)